# Not specifying servername in LDAP connection if it exists in same domain?

Tags: active-directory, server, ldap

Greeting fellow members,

I have a website, which is using AD as login. 
In order to communicate with the LDAP server the connectionstring looks something like this:

```
LDAP://yyyyy.xxx.com/OU=Employees,DC=xxx,DC=com
```

I have heard somewhere that if this server exists in the *same* domain as the website you *don't have to* specify the servername (yyyyy.xxx.com) in the connectionstring. Is this true?

I tried removing this part in the connectionstring above but then it stops working. Am I missing something?

Regards,
Chris

Comment: And you have tried...?

Comment: Just as I wrote. I tried removing the servername so the connectionstring looks like LDAP://OU=Employees,DC=xxx,DC=com. But if gives me an error.

Comment: What error? What language/API are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that in order for this to work I had to leave the domain name in the LDAP connectionString. Like this:

```
LDAP://xxx.com/OU=Employees,DC=xxx,DC=com
```

It was not enought just to leave the "DC" (Domain Component) as the domain name.